# Create URL string from ODataQueryOptions

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi

My task is to create a proxy which sends Get request to another Api and returns its result. I can do it by using HttpClient. When I have a common parameters I can add it by adding to Url. But if Get request contains ODataQueryOptions parameter I have a problem.

Could somebody tell me a way how I can create string from ODataQueryOptions to add it in Get requestUrl

```
        public async Task<PageModel<AnalyticsModel>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<CheckListData> options)
    {
        using var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(HttpClientEnum.SpotApi);
        var optionString = GenerateStringFromOptions(); // I don't now how to write this function
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"{CheckListEndpoints.Get}{options}");
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PageModel<AnalyticsModel>>(responseString);
    }
```

Comment: `"But if Get request contains ODataQueryOptions parameter I have a problem."` Could you please share what problem you are getting? How can your problem be reproduced?

Comment: I can not create correct URL with added ODataQueryOptions information.